# rails has_many through and calling association in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

When in my MechanicsController, the create action works, however, when I check the database, I notice that the taxi never gets a driver_id, I seem to never be able to get the taxi to contain both a mechanic_id and and driver_id at the same time and I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Help would be much appreciated...

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taxis
  has_many :mechanics, :through => :taxis
end


class Mechanic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :driver, :through => :taxis
  has_many :taxis
end


class Taxi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :driver
  belongs_to :mechanic
end

class MechanicsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    this_driver=Driver.find(params[:driver_id])
    @mechanic = this_driver.mechanics.new(params[:mechanic])
    @taxi=@mechanic.taxis.new(params[:queueprocessor])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @mechanic.save
        format.html { redirect_to @mechanic, notice: 'Mechanic was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @mechanic, status: :created, location: @mechanic }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @mechanic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here are my migrations:

```
class CreateDrivers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :drivers do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateMechanics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :mechanics do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Taxis < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :taxis do |t|
      t.belongs_to :driver
      t.belongs_to :mechanic
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.  Change this:

```
class Mechanic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :driver, :through => :taxis
  has_many :taxis
end
```

to this (note that `:driver` is changed to `:drivers`):

```
class Mechanic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taxis
  has_many :drivers, :through => :taxis
end
```

Additionally, in the `create` action, you are attaching the models in the wrong sequence:

```
this_driver=Driver.find(params[:driver_id])
# this_driver.mechanics can't create a new association without a Taxi join model
@mechanic = this_driver.mechanics.new(params[:mechanic])   
@taxi=@mechanic.taxis.new(params[:queueprocessor])
```

Should be changed to:

```
this_driver=Driver.find(params[:driver_id])
@taxi = this_driver.taxis.build(params[:queueprocessor])
@mechanic = @taxi.build_mechanic(params[:mechanic])
```

Comment: Thank you for the input PinnyM. However in the controller, for the line
    @mechanic = @taxi.mechanics.build(params[:mechanic])
I'm getting an _undefined method `mechanics' for nil:NilClass_ error...

Comment: This would indicate that the `@taxi` variable hasn't been set.  Are you sure you put the `@taxi = ...` line before the `@mechanic = ...` line?  calling `this_driver.taxis.build(...)` should have set the `@taxi` variable...

Comment: I'm using the gem better_errors, so I get a console on the webpage. I was able to to display the @taxi variable, it does get initialised successfully and displays the correct params given from the previous page...

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
has_many :driver, :through => :taxis
```

to:

```
has_many :drivers, :through => :taxis
```